# Adding spark-csv dependency in Zeppelin is creating a network error

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, emr, amazon-emr

Adding spark-csv dependency in Zeppelin is creating a network error. 
I went to the Spark interpreter in Zeppelin and added the Spark-csv dependency. `com.databricks:spark-csv_2.10:1.2.0`. I also added it in the argument option.

[image]

I restarted Zeppelin and ran the following command :

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext

val sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc)
val df = sqlContext.read
    .format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
    .option("header", "true") // Use first line of all files as header
    .option("inferSchema", "true") // Automatically infer data types
    .load("https://github.com/databricks/spark-csv/raw/master/src/test/resources/cars.csv")
df.printSchema()
```

[image]

Am I adding the dependency correctly?

UPDATE

Tried changing the library to `com.databricks:spark-csv_2.11:jar:1.6.0` and got the following :

Error setting properties for interpreter 'spark.spark': Could not find artifact com.databricks:spark-csv_2.11:jar:1.6.0 in central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you used pretty old library version, in addition built for scala 2.10 (where your spark seems to be 2.11).

Change the package to `com.databricks:spark-csv_2.11:1.5.0` and it should work.

Comment: Tried changing it to the package you suggested. Spark couldn't find it.

Comment: I've made a typo, proper version is `1.5.0` (see updated answer). Sorry ;-)